# Would it be correct to say: "I haven't had a lot of friends in my life, but I'm grateful for the few that I do have"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, grammaticality

Would it be correct to say: "I haven't had a lot of friends in my life, but I'm grateful for the few that I do have"?

I need to write a speech, and would like to know whether this sentence sounds right, or just plain awkward. Are there any improvements I can make?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds fine. The only change I might make is to use "many" rather than "a lot of", which contrasts nicely with "few".

Comment: Okay, thank you. One more thing: Do I need to add the "have" at the end of the sentence? Or should I leave that out?

Comment: If you leave out the "have", it means that you "do" (have sex with) your friends. Your call.